# Can anyone help me how to pass the parameters in redirect link

Tags: php, opencart

I am inserting the comments into the database after submitting that page I should get the inserted comments for that id as well.

```
<textarea  name="comments"  rows="2" cols="100" placeholder="comments..."></textarea><br/>

     <div class="content form">

  <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_comment; ?>" class=" button" />
```

Here is the view Controller.

I have written the redirect function like this.

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('boutique/customerorder/details'));
```

Here, I should pass the particular customer id to get that details.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('boutique/customerorder/details', 'customer_id=' . $customer_id, 'SSL'));
```